# I could use some help analyzing a transcription I made of the disciples 2 menu theme

Tags: analysis, transcription

I've been transcribing some songs recently, however I feel that I am somewhat limited in actually approaching the analysis of the songs after I have transcribed them.

I have attached a photo of my transcription as well as a soundcloud link to the score being played (I would recommend disabling the auto-play as it tends to play rather annoying songs afterwards. There doesn't seem to be anything I can do to change this).

Anyways It seems like it could be roughly in a locrian mode with some chromatic variation and at measure 9 it changes to E minor? with a #6 chord?

I would appreciate any input on what is happening in this song.

[soundcloud link to file](https://soundcloud.com/user390967767/tracks)

[original song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_GOqhQFOX4)

[image]

Comment: Many years ago I used to play a LP on 45 tours or a tape in double speed to identify better the lower tones and bass notes. I hope this trick could help you, today you can play the youtube video in double speed. The low notes will be transposed an octava then you can listen to it at a lower speed again (e.g. by wavelab) Analysis: I don't think you can indicate this  piece to any key or mode. I would at first sight pretend it is in a free tonality. b.t.w. I also would say some intervals of your transcription are wrong.

Comment: Even if it is atonal, is there anything you could say about chord progressions or cadences or why the piece works? Additionally which parts were wrong?

Comment: well, I should listen to it once more. as far I remember there are more that only this voice line, some chords or other voices. then I think I couldn't identify a D in measure 4 and in bar 8  there I didn't here a second, rather a major third so listen again if this is not G# - E. When I hear this progression (or look at the sheet) I hear at the beginning a le-so (Ab- G) in the 2nd line you could analyse as a minor (augmented 6th and 7th) and something like a neapolitan - but is not N6, as there is not the 3rd the bass tone. The Bb in the last line I would notate as A# (leading tone to B)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this piece can't be analyzed based only on the melody, so an analysis requires transcribing the chords. That level of transcription is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

> help analyzing a transcription ... if G# is the root, b2 b3 ... Roughly locrian sound with chromatic phrasing?

If G# is the root, then it's more Lydian Augmented than Locrian. Lydian #5 has the G (Fx), Cx (D), Dx (E), and A#. The full spelling is G# A# B# Cx Dx E# Fx (or in Ab = Ab Bb C D E F G).

But G# is not the root. It's A. Here's the chord progression:

m.1-2 = E/G#

m.3-4 = G

m.5 = E, A

m.6 = Gm, G

m.7 = A, E

m.8 = E

m.9-10 = E or A

m.11-12 = A/C#, A/E or E

m.13-14 = G

m.15 = G, A

m.16-17 = G, Gm, G, Gm

m.18 = G, A

m.19-20 = G, Gm, G

Based on this analysis, the Key is A minor (harmonic/melodic minor scales allow for the F#'s and G#'s).